# Firebase FCM Sound not Working When Using Real Device and Missing Default Notification Channel

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have some problem about notification sound in fcm. When the notification is send, it doesnt play any sound. Vibration is okay, only sound is missing. Here is my payload from node js.

```
 var payload = {
      notification: {
         title   : 'Antrian ' + data.dokter,
         body    : "Pasien : " + pasien.id + '\nAntrian Anda Kurang : ' + counter + "\nAntrian Sekarang : " + noAntrian,
         sound   : "betelgeuse.ogg"
      }
 };
```

And in the app, I also get Missing Default Channel warning. I put the detail in androidManifest already

```
  <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
      android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />
```

And create string.xml in res/values/

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<resources>
    <string name="default_notification_channel_id" translatable="false">fcm_default_channel</string>
</resources>
```

This is how I handle the message

```
FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(LocalNotification.showNotification);


static Future<void> showNotification(RemoteMessage payload) async {
    var android = AndroidInitializationSettings('logo_rs');
    var initiallizationSettingsIOS = IOSInitializationSettings();
    var initialSetting = new InitializationSettings(android: android, iOS: initiallizationSettingsIOS);
    final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initialSetting);

    // Daftar jenis notifikasi dari aplikasi.

    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidDetails = AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'default_notification_channel_id',
        'Notification',
        'All Notification is Here',
        importance: Importance.max,
        priority: Priority.high,
        ticker: 'ticker',
        icon: "logo_rs",
        sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('betelgeuse'),
        playSound: true,
    );
    const iOSDetails = IOSNotificationDetails();
    const NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(android: androidDetails, iOS: iOSDetails);
    // Menampilkan Notifikasi
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(0, payload.notification!.title, payload.notification!.body, platformChannelSpecifics);
  }
```

Maybe I'm missing something, so any advice is appreciated. Thank you.

**
EDIT : tried using Pixel Emulator and it working, when using my own device, its not working (currently using Pco F1)

Comment: what if you try default sound, sound   : "default"

Comment: Thank you, I tried using emulator and its working fine, but when using real device (xiaomi), it doesn't work.